# Processing Models Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

I've dealt with a problem in [Microsoft Basic Mining tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d8233bb-117e-4563-9302-8a5a8ad1fae2(v=sql.110)).

I done all steps exactly till [Processing Models step.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d8233bb-117e-4563-9302-8a5a8ad1fae2(v=sql.110))

At this point when a ran the processing progress an error occurred.

I took a screenshot of that error.

what is the problem? and how can I solve that?

[image: Processing error]

[image: Processing error 2]

error text:

```html
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Parallel>
    <Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300">
      <Object>
        <DatabaseID>BasicDataMining</DatabaseID>
        <MiningStructureID>Targeted Mailing</MiningStructureID>
      </Object>
      <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
      <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
    </Process>
  </Parallel>
</Batch>
 Processing Mining Structure 'Targeted Mailing' completed.
  Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:32 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:35 AM; Duration: 0:00:02
 Processing Dimension 'Targeted Mailing ~MC-Customer Key' failed.
  Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:32 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:35 AM; Duration: 0:00:02
  Processing Dimension Attribute '(All)' completed.
   Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; Duration: 0:00:00
  Processing Dimension Attribute 'Address Line1' completed. 12798 rows have been read.
   Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:34 AM; Duration: 0:00:01
   SQL queries 1
    SELECT 
  DISTINCT
 [dbo_vTargetMail].[AddressLine1] AS [dbo_vTargetMailAddressLine10_0]
  FROM [dbo].[vTargetMail] AS [dbo_vTargetMail]
  Processing Dimension Attribute 'Address Line2' completed. 168 rows have been read.
   Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:34 AM; Duration: 0:00:01
   SQL queries 1
    SELECT 
  DISTINCT
 [dbo_vTargetMail].[AddressLine2] AS [dbo_vTargetMailAddressLine20_0]
  FROM [dbo].[vTargetMail] AS [dbo_vTargetMail]
  Processing Dimension Attribute 'Bike Buyer' completed. 3 rows have been read.
   Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:34 AM; Duration: 0:00:01
   SQL queries 1
    SELECT 
  DISTINCT
 [dbo_vTargetMail].[BikeBuyer] AS [dbo_vTargetMailBikeBuyer0_0]
  FROM [dbo].[vTargetMail] AS [dbo_vTargetMail]
  Processing Dimension Attribute 'Commute Distance' completed. 6 rows have been read.
   Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:34 AM; Duration: 0:00:01
   SQL queries 1
    SELECT 
  DISTINCT
 [dbo_vTargetMail].[CommuteDistance] AS [dbo_vTargetMailCommuteDistance0_0]
  FROM [dbo].[vTargetMail] AS [dbo_vTargetMail]
  Processing Dimension Attribute 'Customer Key' failed. 10000 rows have been read.
   Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:34 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:35 AM; Duration: 0:00:00
   Error Messages 2
    Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key cannot be found when processing: Table: 'dbo_vTargetMail', Column: 'AddressLine1', Value: '8011 McNutt Ave'. The attribute is 'Address Line1'. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key was converted to an unknown member because the attribute key was not found. Attribute Customer Key of Dimension: Targeted Mailing ~MC-Customer Key from Database: BasicDataMining, Record: 12749.
    Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key cannot be found when processing: Table: 'dbo_vTargetMail', Column: 'AddressLine1', Value: '8011 McNutt Ave'. The attribute is 'Address Line1'. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key was converted to an unknown member because the attribute key was not found. Attribute Customer Key of Dimension: Targeted Mailing ~MC-Customer Key from Database: BasicDataMining, Record: 12749. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The process operation ended because the number of errors encountered during processing reached the defined limit of allowable errors for the operation. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Customer Key' attribute of the 'Targeted Mailing ~MC-Customer Key' dimension from the 'BasicDataMining' database was being processed.
   SQL queries 1
    SELECT 
  DISTINCT
 [dbo_vTargetMail].[CustomerKey] AS [dbo_vTargetMailCustomerKey0_0],[dbo_vTargetMail].[AddressLine1] AS [dbo_vTargetMailAddressLine10_1],[dbo_vTargetMail].[AddressLine2] AS [dbo_vTargetMailAddressLine20_2],[dbo_vTargetMail].[BikeBuyer] AS [dbo_vTargetMailBikeBuyer0_3],[dbo_vTargetMail].[CommuteDistance] AS [dbo_vTargetMailCommuteDistance0_4],[dbo_vTargetMail].[EmailAddress] AS [dbo_vTargetMailEmailAddress0_5],[dbo_vTargetMail].[EnglishEducation] AS [dbo_vTargetMailEnglishEducation0_6],[dbo_vTargetMail].[EnglishOccupation] AS [dbo_vTargetMailEnglishOccupation0_7],[dbo_vTargetMail].[FirstName] AS [dbo_vTargetMailFirstName0_8],[dbo_vTargetMail].[Gender] AS [dbo_vTargetMailGender0_9],[dbo_vTargetMail].[GeographyKey] AS [dbo_vTargetMailGeographyKey0_10],[dbo_vTargetMail].[HouseOwnerFlag] AS [dbo_vTargetMailHouseOwnerFlag0_11],[dbo_vTargetMail].[LastName] AS [dbo_vTargetMailLastName0_12],[dbo_vTargetMail].[MaritalStatus] AS [dbo_vTargetMailMaritalStatus0_13],[dbo_vTargetMail].[NumberCarsOwned] AS [dbo_vTargetMailNumberCarsOwned0_14],[dbo_vTargetMail].[NumberChildrenAtHome] AS [dbo_vTargetMailNumberChildrenAtHome0_15],[dbo_vTargetMail].[Region] AS [dbo_vTargetMailRegion0_16],[dbo_vTargetMail].[TotalChildren] AS [dbo_vTargetMailTotalChildren0_17]
  FROM [dbo].[vTargetMail] AS [dbo_vTargetMail]
  ORDER BY [dbo_vTargetMail].[CustomerKey]
  ASC
  Processing Dimension Attribute 'Email Address' completed. 18485 rows have been read.
   Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:34 AM; Duration: 0:00:01
   SQL queries 1
    SELECT 
  DISTINCT
 [dbo_vTargetMail].[EmailAddress] AS [dbo_vTargetMailEmailAddress0_0]
  FROM [dbo].[vTargetMail] AS [dbo_vTargetMail]
  Processing Dimension Attribute 'English Education' completed. 6 rows have been read.
   Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; Duration: 0:00:00
   SQL queries 1
    SELECT 
  DISTINCT
 [dbo_vTargetMail].[EnglishEducation] AS [dbo_vTargetMailEnglishEducation0_0]
  FROM [dbo].[vTargetMail] AS [dbo_vTargetMail]
  Processing Dimension Attribute 'English Occupation' completed. 6 rows have been read.
   Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:34 AM; Duration: 0:00:01
   SQL queries 1
    SELECT 
  DISTINCT
 [dbo_vTargetMail].[EnglishOccupation] AS [dbo_vTargetMailEnglishOccupation0_0]
  FROM [dbo].[vTargetMail] AS [dbo_vTargetMail]
  Processing Dimension Attribute 'First Name' completed. 671 rows have been read.
   Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:34 AM; Duration: 0:00:01
   SQL queries 1
    SELECT 
  DISTINCT
 [dbo_vTargetMail].[FirstName] AS [dbo_vTargetMailFirstName0_0]
  FROM [dbo].[vTargetMail] AS [dbo_vTargetMail]
  Processing Dimension Attribute 'Gender' completed. 3 rows have been read.
   Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:34 AM; Duration: 0:00:01
   SQL queries 1
    SELECT 
  DISTINCT
 [dbo_vTargetMail].[Gender] AS [dbo_vTargetMailGender0_0]
  FROM [dbo].[vTargetMail] AS [dbo_vTargetMail]
  Processing Dimension Attribute 'Geography Key' completed. 337 rows have been read.
   Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:34 AM; Duration: 0:00:01
   SQL queries 1
    SELECT 
  DISTINCT
 [dbo_vTargetMail].[GeographyKey] AS [dbo_vTargetMailGeographyKey0_0]
  FROM [dbo].[vTargetMail] AS [dbo_vTargetMail]
  Processing Dimension Attribute 'House Owner Flag' completed. 3 rows have been read.
   Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; Duration: 0:00:00
   SQL queries 1
    SELECT 
  DISTINCT
 [dbo_vTargetMail].[HouseOwnerFlag] AS [dbo_vTargetMailHouseOwnerFlag0_0]
  FROM [dbo].[vTargetMail] AS [dbo_vTargetMail]
  Processing Dimension Attribute 'Last Name' completed. 376 rows have been read.
   Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:34 AM; Duration: 0:00:01
   SQL queries 1
    SELECT 
  DISTINCT
 [dbo_vTargetMail].[LastName] AS [dbo_vTargetMailLastName0_0]
  FROM [dbo].[vTargetMail] AS [dbo_vTargetMail]
  Processing Dimension Attribute 'Marital Status' completed. 3 rows have been read.
   Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; Duration: 0:00:00
   SQL queries 1
    SELECT 
  DISTINCT
 [dbo_vTargetMail].[MaritalStatus] AS [dbo_vTargetMailMaritalStatus0_0]
  FROM [dbo].[vTargetMail] AS [dbo_vTargetMail]
  Processing Dimension Attribute 'Number Cars Owned' completed. 6 rows have been read.
   Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:34 AM; Duration: 0:00:01
   SQL queries 1
    SELECT 
  DISTINCT
 [dbo_vTargetMail].[NumberCarsOwned] AS [dbo_vTargetMailNumberCarsOwned0_0]
  FROM [dbo].[vTargetMail] AS [dbo_vTargetMail]
  Processing Dimension Attribute 'Number Children At Home' completed. 7 rows have been read.
   Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; Duration: 0:00:00
   SQL queries 1
    SELECT 
  DISTINCT
 [dbo_vTargetMail].[NumberChildrenAtHome] AS [dbo_vTargetMailNumberChildrenAtHome0_0]
  FROM [dbo].[vTargetMail] AS [dbo_vTargetMail]
  Processing Dimension Attribute 'Region' completed. 4 rows have been read.
   Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; Duration: 0:00:00
   SQL queries 1
    SELECT 
  DISTINCT
 [dbo_vTargetMail].[Region] AS [dbo_vTargetMailRegion0_0]
  FROM [dbo].[vTargetMail] AS [dbo_vTargetMail]
  Processing Dimension Attribute 'Total Children' completed. 7 rows have been read.
   Start time: 3/24/2015 10:18:33 AM; End time: 3/24/2015 10:18:34 AM; Duration: 0:00:01
   SQL queries 1
    SELECT 
  DISTINCT
 [dbo_vTargetMail].[TotalChildren] AS [dbo_vTargetMailTotalChildren0_0]
  FROM [dbo].[vTargetMail] AS [dbo_vTargetMail]
Errors and Warnings from Response
 Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.
 Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The process operation ended because the number of errors encountered during processing reached the defined limit of allowable errors for the operation.
 Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Customer Key' attribute of the 'Targeted Mailing ~MC-Customer Key' dimension from the 'BasicDataMining' database was being processed.
 Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The process operation ended because the number of errors encountered during processing reached the defined limit of allowable errors for the operation.
 Server: The operation has been cancelled.
 Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key cannot be found when processing: Table: 'dbo_vTargetMail', Column: 'AddressLine1', Value: '8011 McNutt Ave'. The attribute is 'Address Line1'.
 Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key was converted to an unknown member because the attribute key was not found. Attribute Customer Key of Dimension: Targeted Mailing ~MC-Customer Key from Database: BasicDataMining, Record: 12749.
```

Comment: I cannot read that. Can you?

Comment: sorry for that, but if you save that you can read it.also I uploaded another image. thanks for your attention.